# Bash script handles command line argument incorrectly

Tags: bash

I got a script that uses two command line arguments.

`./metagwastoolkit.run.sh metagwastoolkit.model1.conf metagwastoolkit.files.model1.list`

Later on in the script I do this:

`echo "cat meta.results.out | parseTable.pl --col VARIANTID,P_SQRTN,P_FIXED,P_RANDOM | awk ' $2 == 0 || $3 == 0 || $4 == 0 { print $1, $2, $3, $4 } ' > meta.results.needs_p_fixing.out"  > meta.p_corrector.sh`

And that is not producing what I want, it produces:

`cat meta.results.out | parseTable.pl --col VARIANTID,P_SQRTN,P_FIXED,P_RANDOM | awk ' metagwastoolkit.files.model1.list == 0 ||  == 0 ||  == 0 { print metagwastoolkit.model1.conf,metagwastoolkit.files.model1.list,, }' > meta.results.needs_p_fixing.out`

So it takes my configuration file as $1 and my files.list as $2… which is obviously not what I want… I expect it to print the columns 1 through 4 from the pipe if fields 2, 3, or 4 are equal to 0.

How can I change this…?

Best,

Sander

Comment: What exactly is it not doing right?? If it is a variable overwrite/substitution issue, I suspect your `source ${1}` may overwrite variable names in your current script with values from the sourced file from that point forward, but I'm not following how you contend the arguments `$1` and `$2` are not containing what you want?

Comment: As I read it, your `awk ' **$2 == 0 || $3 == 0 || $4 == 0 { print $1, $2, $3, $4** } '` does not appear to be doing what you think it does. Double check the `awk` syntax.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You never use `CONFIGURATIONFILE` or `GWASFILE` anywhere in the script.

Comment: That `awk` script looks like invalid syntax. What do you expect `**` to do in `awk`?

Comment: Indeed. The `awk` doesn't do what I want. I want it to take the fields from `cat /hpc/dhl_ec/svanderlaan/projects/meta_gwasfabp4/METAFABP4_1000G/MODEL1/META/meta.results.FABP4.1Gp1.EUR.aaa.out | /hpc/local/CentOS7/dhl_ec/software/MetaGWASToolKit/SCRIPTS/parseTable.pl --col VARIANTID,P_SQRTN,P_FIXED,P_RANDOM | `. Which means I expect `awk` to take the fields from that pipe, i.e. those columns in bold. Instead it takes my two command line arguments, which I, as I was under the assumption, had reassigned to `$CONFIGURATIONFILE` and `$GWASFILES`.

Comment: Don't put syntax highlighting in code blocks, it doesn't work and just confuses us because we think it's part of the code.

Comment: @Barmar I haven't put in the whole script, that's more than 800 lines. Plus the ** were just meant to point the commenters to right section - i.e. these stars aren't in the code. Changed it.

Comment: So the problem you're having is that shell variables are getting substituted into the `awk` command. Variables don't get expanded inside single-quoted strings, so I don't see how that's possible, unless you're doing something you haven't shown clearly.

Comment: None of the variable assignments in the script you posted at the top are at all relevant to this problem.

Comment: Oh. I would have thought the way I handle the two commandline arguments matters. But anyway: if you have a solution it would be great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143961/discussion-between-sander-w-van-der-laan-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was that inside the `echo` the variables are replaced by the command line arguments, which is not my intention. The solution is to escape the `$`-signs.

The working line is:

`echo "cat meta.results.out | parseTable.pl --col VARIANTID,P_SQRTN,P_FIXED,P_RANDOM | awk '\$2 == 0 || \$3 == 0 || \$4 == 0 { print \$1, \$2, \$3, \$4 }' > meta.results.needs_p_fixing.out" > meta.p_corrector.sh`

Which does what I want: take check whether fields of column 2, 3, and 4 of the pipe are equal to 0 and print these.

Kudos to @Barmar for getting me to the solution.

Best,

Sander